Partitions of $\mathbb{Z}$ with specific restrictions
I am studying partitions of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the following properties.

For a fixed $w \in \mathbb{N},  w = 1 \mod 3$

The partition is into three sets: $S, U, V$

$0 \in S$

$n \in S \implies -n \in S$

$U = S + w$

$V = S - w$


When $w = 1$, it is easy to deduce that $S = 3 \mathbb{Z}$.
In any case, $V = -U$.
I suspect that $S = 3 \mathbb{Z}$ for all cases but I am struggling to prove it.  I am trying the $w = 4$ case and trying to get contradictions for exceptions to the expected pattern but it is getting very messy.
I hope that if I can solve the $w = 4$ case then I will be able to find an induction argument for the other cases.
I am wondering whether I have missed a simpler argument.
Of course, I could be wrong but I have not found a counterexample yet either.

For $w=7$, you can take for $S$ the union of the equivalence classes of $0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\bmod 21.$

Thank you.  If you make that an answer then I would accept it.

For the problem which I am modelling, it violates another condition which I did not state.  Of course, since i did not state it, it does not detract from the validity of your answer.  It is still valuable since I now know that my expectations cannot be proved without the extra condition.

Feel free to edit your question with that additional condition. Since no one else engaged with the question yet, that should be fine.
